# solr word count, word by word in a sentence

Tags: solr, facet

```
{
id: "1698627066",
screen_name: "RomanceInfinity",
text: [
"Going NYP to have lunch with bro because I got too much time in between!!!",
"nyp"
],
stance: "",
source: "<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>",
fromid: "411377814521147392",
favourite: "false",
date: "2013-12-13 14:11:28",
replyto: "",
replytoid: "",
retweetfrom: "",
domaintype: "",
keywords: [
"nyp"
],
ratio: "",
latitude: 1000,
longitude: 1000,
retweet: 0,
mood_joy: "0.0",
mood_sadness: "0.0",
mood_surprised: "0.0",
mood_disgusted: "0.0",
mood_anger: "1.0",
_version_: 1454285708574326800
},
{
```

Is there a way that I count each word in the sentence using facet " Going NYP to have lunch with bro because I got too much time in between!!"?
 
For example having a results of Going =1 Nyp =1  lunch =1 and also not counting the punctuation?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `text` from the dict using:

```
name_of_dict['text'][0]
```

This will extract the sentence:

```
Going NYP to have lunch with bro because I got too much time in between!!!
```

To ignore any punctuation you can use a function such as `.replace()` via:

```
str = "Going NYP to have lunch with bro because I got too much time in between!!!";
print str.replace("!", "");
>>> Going NYP to have lunch with bro because I got too much time in between
```

Last, I refer you to this post for counting occurance in a string:

[Efficiently calculate word frequency in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919604/efficiently-calculate-word-frequency-in-a-string)

To which a viable solution is:

```
from collections import Counter

test = 'abc def abc def zzz zzz'
Counter(test.split()).most_common()
[('abc', 2), ('zzz', 2), ('def', 2)]
```

Comment: where do you add this in a solr document? or is there any queries in can run?