# Python - Finding most occurring words in a CSV row

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, csv, numpy

I want to find the most occurring substring in a CSV row either by itself, or by using a list of keywords for lookup.

I've found a way to find out the top 5 most occurring words in each row of a CSV file using Python using the below responses, but, that doesn't solve my purpose. It gives me results like -

```
[(' Trojan.PowerShell.LNK.Gen.2', 3),
(' Suspicious ZIP!lnk', 2),
(' HEUR:Trojan-Downloader.WinLNK.Powedon.a', 2),
(' TROJ_FR.8D496570', 2),
('Trojan.PowerShell.LNK.Gen.2', 1),
(' Trojan.PowerShell.LNK.Gen.2 (B)', 1),
(' Win32.Trojan-downloader.Powedon.Lrsa', 1),
(' PowerShell.DownLoader.466', 1),
(' malware (ai score=86)', 1),
(' Probably LNKScript', 1),
(' virus.lnk.powershell.a', 1),
(' Troj/LnkPS-A', 1),
(' Trojan.LNK', 1)]
```

Whereas, I would want something like 'Trojan', 'Downloader', 'Powershell' ... as the top results.

The matching words can be a substring of a value (cell) in the CSV or can be a combination of two or more words. Can someone help fix this either by using a keywords list or without.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently calculate word frequency in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919604/efficiently-calculate-word-frequency-in-a-string)

Comment: Please print `df.head(5)` and post it here. This does not qualify as a valid example.

Answer (score 0):

Let, `my_values = ['A',  'B',  'C',  'A',  'Z',  'Z'  ,'X' , 'A' ,'X','H','D' ,'A','S',  'A',  'Z']` is your list of words which is to sort.

Now take a list which will store information of occurrences of every words.

```
count_dict={}
```

Populate the dictionary with appropriate values :

```
for i in my_values:
    if count_dict.get(i)==None: #If the value is not present in the dictionary then this is the first occurrence of the value
        count_dict[i]=1
    else:
        count_dict[i] = count_dict[i]+1 #If previously found then increment it's value
```

Now sort the values of `dict` according to their occurrences :

```
sorted_items= sorted(count_dict.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
```

Now you have your expected results!
The most occurring 3 values  are:

```
print(sorted_items[:3])
```

output :

```
[('A', 5), ('Z', 3), ('X', 2)]
```

The most occurring 2 values are :

```
print(sorted_items[:3])
```

output:

```
[('A', 5), ('Z', 3)]
```

and so on.

Comment: `Counter` reinvented unnecessarily.

Comment: Will you be more specific please?

Comment: @TaohidulIslam this gives me " " as the most occurring string, and also doesn't account for substrings in each value. I think this is just considering the whole value of each cell in the CSV row. any fix for that?

Comment: Please provide a list of your actual data.

Comment: Give data list from which you want to get your expected result.